# What drivers are required for me to project my laptop

Tags: windows-10

I want to project the display from my Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series laptop to my Samsung Smart tv. My runs Windows 10.

What drivers are required for me to do this?

Comment: No; drivers are required; use an hdmi/display port to hdmi cable and/or Miracast if your tv supports it

Comment: @Ramhound You should post that as an answer since it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the regular graphics outputs on a laptop (DP, DVI, VGA or HDMI) then no additional<sup>*1</sup> drivers are needed. Just plug in the cable to the TV, right click on the desktop and select 'display settings'. Extend the desktop to the TV and you can use it. Alsternative you can mirror the screen but then you usually get restricted to the lowest resolution of either internal display and TV.

Now if you are trying to use specific smart TV features (e.g. sent a display via the network) then things might be different, but that is both an edge case and not mentioned in the post.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: Additional as in: It sort of will work without graphics driver. At low resolution. But you are extremely unlike to now have those installed.